# is there any need to have azure backup plan?

Tags: azure, backup

I want know is there any need to have  backup plan? I am just curious about if azure have its policy that they can maintain backup of all application they have installed on there server so is there any need to take extra plan to have separate backup of our own code and database ? Please guide me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This purely depends upon the product which you are going to develop/host within Azure. There are several factors like ***SLA(Service Level Agreements), Compliances, Audit/Policies*** etc.,

Let say if your product related to healthcare/financial domain. In such a case, you need to follow certain policies, compliances.

Healthcare related products should be [HIPAA compliances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act)

Financial/Cards products should be [PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act)

You can find all the list of compliance with Azure [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/compliance/complianceofferings)

The Answer may be **not be needed**. Azure has a lot of services for managing backups. If your project/product is compliance, Audit, and policies approved by Azure. Then you don't really need a separate backup from your side.